# Remove validation from entry field

Tags: jquery, validation

I have a form that has been built where the div "TotalDayOutofOffice" automatically calculates based on the two dates that have been provided. The problem is, the validation on this field does not allow for decimals to be added, so if someone wanted to half a day's holiday, they're not able to submit the request (whether it be entered as "0.5 day" or "1/2 day".

I've added the code below which I think includes the validation requirements.

My knowledge of code is not particularly great, so any assistance anyone can offer here is greatly appreciated.

```
// Numeric Validation 
      var totalDays = $(".divTotalDayOutofOffice input[type=text]").val();
      if (totalDays != ''){
      if (/^[0-9]{1,3}$/.test(totalDays)){

      }
      else {
         ttext = "\<a href='javascript:void(0);' onclick='SetTotalFocus();'\>\<b\> " + mandatoryfieldsdesc[1]+"\</a\> \<br\>";
         $(".divTotalDayOutofOffice .rn_TextInput>div>label").addClass("rn_ErrorLabel");
         $(".divTotalDayOutofOffice .rn_TextInput>input").addClass("rn_ErrorField");
         this._errorMessageDiv.append(ttext);
         errorFlag = true;  
      } 
      }


      if (errorFlag){
           return false;
      }
      else {
          return true;
      }



    /**
     * Overridable methods from FormSubmit:
     *
     * Call `this.parent()` inside of function bodies
     * (with expected parameters) to call the parent
     * method being overridden.
     */
    // _onButtonClick: function(evt)
    // _fireSubmitRequest: function()
    // _onFormValidated: function()
    // _onFormValidationFail: function()
    // _formSubmitResponse: function(type, args)
    // _onFormUpdated: function()
    // _onErrorResponse: function()
    // _displayErrorDialog: function(message)
    // _onFormTokenUpdate: function(type, args)
    // _enableFormExpirationWatch: function()
    // _toggleLoadingIndicators: function(turnOn)
    // _toggleClickListener: function(enable)
    },

     _formatDate : function (date) {
        var d = new Date(date),
        month = '' + (d.getMonth() + 1),
        day = '' + d.getDate(),
        year = d.getFullYear();

        if (month.length < 2) month = '0' + month;
        if (day.length < 2) day = '0' + day;

        return [year, month, day].join('/');
       }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can replace this regex test:

```
if (/^[0-9]{1,3}$/.test(totalDays)){
```

with:

```
if (/^[0-9]{1,3}\.?[0-9]{1,2}?$/.test(totalDays)){
```

This will allow you to validate floating point values too, there is restriction of at most **2** numbers after point **.**

Comment: Hi,

Thanks for your help - I managed to delete the whole validation itself which worked.